# Find objects through objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A post belongs to a discussion, a discussion belongs to a forum.

Say I have the forum object:

```
forum #=> <Forum:#>
```

From it, how should I return all posts that belong to the forum's discussions? Easy enough to return all discussions that belong to a forum, but not the posts that, through discussions, belong to the forum.

(btw I'm not building a forum just an example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get that second level you can use [has_many :through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)
For example:

```
class Discussion < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Forum < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :discussions
  has_many :posts, through: :discussions
end

# get all posts in all discussions in the forum.
Forum.find(1).posts
```